# Почему появляется дополнительная рамка у ссылок на айфонах?

Tags: html, вёрстка, border

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете подсказать. Сверстал сайт, в футере список из ссылок, у них задан ховер (ссылки меняют цвет на белый) и все, на пк и андроидах все нормально при нажатии на эти ссылки, а при нажатии на ссылку на айфоне, появляется вот такая рамка, как на скриншоте, посмотрел весть css файл, там нет никаких бордеров при нажатии или наведении. Как убрать эту рамку?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  
  
  
  
</head>
<body>
 

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer class="footer">
    
      <div class="container">
       
        <div class="footer__wrapper">
          <div class="footer__item">
            <h3 class="footer__title">
              НАШИ МАШИНЫ
            </h3>
            <div class="footer__text">
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Mercedes S-Class</a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Mercedes V-Class</a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Mercedes E-Class</a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Rolls-Royce Ghost</a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Rolls-Royce Phantom</a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__link">Bentley Mulsanne</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.footer__wrapper -->
        <div class="copyright">
          2010-2018 ©Pegasus Luxury Services Ltd. Company Number: 08104782. PCO-Operator Licence: 0086810101. All rights reserved.
        </div>  
      </div><!-- /.container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Javascript -->

  <script src="app.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Romul';
  src: url('../fonts/romul.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/romul.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/romul.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/romul.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}


body {
  margin: 0;

  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #fefeff;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 35px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2f2c34;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;

  border: 1px solid #2f2c34;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear, border .2s linear;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d0aa8c;
  border: 1px solid #d0aa8c;
}


/* Header 
============================= */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;

  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #2f2c34;
}

.header__item {
  margin-right: 75px;
  align-content: center;
}

.header__phone {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2f2c34;
}

.header__description {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #d0aa8c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__description:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 7px;
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #d0aa8c;
}

.header__logo {
  position: absolute;

  top: 34%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.header__buttons {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.header__btn {
  margin-right: 25px;
}


/* Main menu
============================= */

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2f2c34;
}

.nav__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;

  
  align-items: center;
}


.nav__link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 74px;
  font-family: 'Romul', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;

  border-right: 1px solid #737176;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.nav__item:last-child .nav__link {
  padding-right: 0;
  border-right: none;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #d0aa8c;
}

/* Breadcrumbs
============================= */

.breadcrumbs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e9;
}

.breadcrumbs__item {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.breadcrumbs__link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #332f36;
    
  border-left: 1px solid #332f36;
    
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color .2s linear, border-left .2s linear;
}

.breadcrumbs__item:first-child .breadcrumbs__link {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.breadcrumbs__link:hover {
  color: #d0aa8c;
  border-left: 1px solid #d0aa8c
}

.breadcrumbs__link.active {
  color: #d0aa8c;
  border-left: 1px solid #d0aa8c;
}


/* Section
============================= */

.section {
  padding: 30px 0 50px;
}

.section__header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto 45px;

  text-align: center;
}

.section__suptitle {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2f2c34;

  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section__title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  font-family: 'Romul', sans-serif;
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2f2c34;
    
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

.section__title:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #d0aa8c;
}

.section__title:after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #d0aa8c;
}

.section__text {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343434;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.section__text p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Excursions
============================= */

.excursions {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.excursions__item {
  margin-bottom: 42px;
  max-width: 47%;
  text-align: center;
}

.excursions__img {
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.excursions__img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}

.excursions__img a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.excursions__img a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
}

.excursions__img a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.excursions__img a:hover:before,
.excursions__img a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.excursions__title {
  font-family: 'Romul', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2f2c34;

  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.excursions__text {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343434;
}

.excursions__title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 90px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 25px auto;

  background-color: #d0aa8c;
}

.excursions__text p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.excursions__button {
  padding: 9px 80px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #2f2c34;
}

.excursions__button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #d0aa8c;
}

/* Footer
============================= */

.footer {
  min-height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
  url("../images/footer.jpg") center/cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer__item {
  margin: 30px 0 35px;
}

.footer__item:nth-child(3) {
  padding-right: 90px;
  border-right: 1px solid #979695;
}

.footer__title {
  font-family: 'Romul', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer__title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 68px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0 30px;

  background-color: #d0aa8c;
}

.footer__text {
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  border-left: 1px solid #979695;
}

.footer__item:first-child .footer__text {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-left: none;
}


.footer__link {
  display: block;

  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #979695;

  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.footer__link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Footer communication
============================= */

.footer__communication {
  margin: 30px 0 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer__menu {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.footer__info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 13px 7px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #979695;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #979695;

  transition: color .2s linear, border-bottom .2s linear;
}

.footer__info:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer__info:hover {
  color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff
}


.footer__connection {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}

.connection__item {
  margin: 3px 15px 3px;
}

.connection__item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer__phone {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;

  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__description {
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #9a9a9a;

  text-align: right;
}

.footer__social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer__social a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #9a9a9a;

  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.footer__social a:hover {
  color: #d0aa8c;
}

/* Copyright
============================= */

.copyright {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

/* Burger
============================= */

.burger {
  display: none;
  padding: 9px 2px;

  background: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger__item {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 3px;

  background-color: #fff;

  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;

  position: relative;
}

.burger__item:before,
.burger__item:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;

  background-color: #fff;

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.burger__item:before {
  width: 30px;
  top: -8px;
}

.burger__item:after {
  width: 26px;
  bottom: -8px;
}

/* Media
============================= */

@media (min-width: 1700px) {

  /* Container */
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }

    /* Header */
  .header__wrapper {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }

  .header__phone {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .header__description {
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  /* Btn */
  .btn  {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  /* Navigation */
  .nav__wrapper {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }

  .nav__link {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  /* Breadcrumbs */
  .breadcrumbs__link {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  /* Section */
  .section__header {
    max-width: 850px;
    }

  .section__suptitle {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .section__title {
    font-size: 52px;
  }

  .section__text {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  /* Excursion */
  .excursions__title {
    font-size: 31px;
  }

  .excursions__title:after {
    width: 170px;
    height: 2px;
  }

  .excursions__text {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .excursions__button {
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  /* Footer */
  .footer__title {
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .footer__link {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  .footer__info {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  .footer__phone {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  .footer__description {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .footer__social a {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 1170px) {
    
  /* Header */
  .header__inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: none;
  }

  .header__item {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .header__btn {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }


  /* Footer */

  .footer__text {
    margin-left: -50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
    
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  
  /* Navigation */

  .nav__wrapper {
    max-width: 900px;
  }

  .nav__link {
    padding-right: 46px;
  }

  /* Section */
  .section__suptitle {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .section__title {
    font-size: 31px;
  }

  /* Excursions */
  .excursions__title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  /* Footer */

  .footer__text {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-left: none;
  }

  .footer__item:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 0;
    border-right: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 790px) {
  
  /* Burger */

  .burger {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 23px 0;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  /* Section */
  .section {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  /* Header */
  .header__wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    padding: 15px 15px 20px;
    height: 90px;
    
    background-color: #e3d5ca;
  }

  .header__inner {
    display: none;
  }

  .header__logo {
    top: 43%;
  }

  .header__logo img {
    width: 181px;
    height: 63px;
  }

  /* Breadcrumbs */
  .breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Navigation */
  .nav {
    display: none; 

    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav.show {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 45px;
    top: 0%;
  }

  .nav__wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .nav__link {
    
    padding: 7px 3px;
    border-right: none;
  }

  /* Excursions */

  .excursions__title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .excursions__title:after {
    margin: 12px auto;
  }

  .excursions__button {
    padding: 8px 40px;
  }

  /* Footer */

  .footer__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .footer__item {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 10px 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer__communication {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .footer__title:after {
    margin: 15px auto;
  }

  .footer__link {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .footer__info {
    padding: 11px 1px 7px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #d0aa8c;
    transition: color .2s linear, border .2s linear;
  }

  .footer__info:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff
  }

  .footer__phone {
    font-size: 23px;
  }

  .footer__description {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .connection__item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;;
  }

  .footer__social a {
    font-size: 60px;
  }

  /* Copyright */

  .copyright {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  
  /* Section */
  .section {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .section__header {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  /* Excursuions */
  .excursions__item {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .excursions__title {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  .excursions__button {
    padding: 10px 80px;
  }

  /* Footer */

  .footer__phone {
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .footer__communication {
    width: 70%;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 500px) {

  /* Header */
  .header__logo {
    z-index: 11;
  }

  /* Nav */
  .nav {
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .nav__wrapper {
    padding: 70px 10px 3px;
  }

  /* Excursions */
  .excursions__item {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .excursions__button {
    padding: 13px 70px;
  }

  /* Btn */
  .btn {
    color: #000;
  }

  

}
```

Comment: Возможно это outline.

Comment: не аутлайны и бордер none, все перепробовал, не помогло

Comment: попробуй  `-webkit-appearance: none;` [читать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Comment: тоже не помогло, рамка появляется только в сафари, в хроме на айфоне все норм